# Integrate a leaflet map into Shiny without the pipe operator %>%

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, pipeline

OK I have been able to integrate maps into Shinny, but always when I use the pipe operator. This time I have a map that has a for loop and as I am new to R, I didn't know how to use the pipe operator in that case.

The leaflet map is as follows:

libraries used:

```
library(data.table)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
```

data.table:

```
lat<-c(40.41766, 40.43305 ,40.43687, 40.39563, 40.39088, 40.39215, 40.39458, 40.40451, 40.40627, 40.40864)
lng<-c(-3.701328, -3.709352, -3.708531, -3.736556, -3.734796, -3.741867, -3.741222, -3.705399, -3.710980, -3.710310)
colors<-c("#3D00FFFF","#52FF00FF","#3D00FFFF","#0052FFFF","#52FF00FF","#52FF00FF","#52FF00FF","#0052FFFF","#3D00FFFF","#0052FFFF")
name<-as.factor(c("Rafa","Luis","Rafa","Belen","Luis","Luis","Luis","Belen","Rafa","Belen"))
hour_range<-c("Sleeping_Hours","Morning_rush_hours","Morning_Working_Hours","Sleeping_Hours","Morning_rush_hours","Morning_Working_Hours","Sleeping_Hours","Morning_rush_hours","Morning_Working_Hours","Morning_Working_Hours")

data<- data.table(name,lat,lng,hour_range,colors)
```

leaflet map:

```
map<-  leaflet(data)
map<- addTiles(map)
for( name in unique(data$name)){ 
  map<- addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Morning_rush_hours",],color=~colors)
  map<-addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Sleeping_Hours",],color=~colors)
}

map
```

This map works fine the problem is that I don't know how to integrate it with shinny, cause I am not using pipes. And it appears me an error called:

Argument "map" is missing with no default. Because Shiny doesn't see my map.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXLQz.png)

Comment: You haven't shown us the line that generated that error message, or the code you were trying to use to display it in Shiny (which might be the same line).  Try to make your example complete and you're more likely to get useful help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the name and hour_range variables. It is not good practice to use leaflet without pipes, but understanding what you are trying to do I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following example. And also try to run it, when you uncomment the last call to `my_map` in `renderLeaflet`. This is the return value of the function and if you dont call it, nothing will happen.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

data = data.frame(
  lng = runif(100,15,16),
  lat = runif(100,45,50)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    my_map <- leaflet(data)
    my_map <- addTiles(map =  my_map)
    for (i in 1:3) {
      my_map <- addCircleMarkers(map = my_map, lat = ~lat, lng = ~lng)
      my_map <- addCircleMarkers(map = my_map, lat = ~lat * i/10, lng = ~lng * i/10, color ="red")
      my_map <- addCircleMarkers(map = my_map, lat = ~lat * i/30, lng = ~lng * i/30, color ="green")
    }

    ## Uncomment the next line, to see whats happening.
    my_map
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks ! yes I needed to call the map =)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed make the map without pipes if you need to. Look at the following using the data you provided:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        my_map <- leaflet(data)
        my_map <- addTiles(map =  my_map)
        my_map <- addMarkers(map = my_map, lat = ~lat, lng = ~lng)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The output is the same as when you run it with the pipes. I first assign the map created by `leaflet` to an object called `my_map`. Then I just add the extra argument of `map = my_map` in subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks. I will give you some more info. Look the leaflet map is as follows and it works fine:

```
map<-  leaflet(data)
map<- addTiles(map)
for( name in unique(data$name)){ 
  map<- addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Morning_rush_hours",],color=~colors)
  map<-addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Sleeping_Hours",],color=~colors)
}
```

but then I add it into shiny and it doesnt detect the map, when I use pipes it works, but in this case as I am using a for loop and then I dont know how to use the pipes:

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("samplemap")
)

server<-function(input,output){
  output$samplemap<-renderLeaflet({map<-  leaflet(data)
  map<- addTiles(map)
  for( name in unique(data$name)){ 
    map<- addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Morning_rush_hours",],color=~colors)
    map<-addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Sleeping_Hours",],color=~colors)
  }
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I think the mistake is that I am not calling the map, or smth like this.

Hopefully you can help with it,

Comment: Yes, call `map` in your `renderLeaflet`. That should be the last thing you call in that function.